# Is upper hemi-continuity and upper semi-continuity the same thing for set-valued function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Despite of difference in their name, they seem to be the same definition. Some texts use the name "hemi-continuity", others use the other name; none of those notes clarify the difference between hemi-continuity.

A [Caltech note](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~kcborder/Courses/Notes/Correspondences.pdf) says:

> The term semicontinuity is used by many authors to mean hemicontinuity.

I wonder if this is correct in general.

Comment: In the economics literature at least, upper semi-continuous is defined for set correspondences (at least for the first proof of Berge's Theorem I found online). Wikipedia does not do that, and instead defines a semi-continuous function on real-valued functions, and says that an upper semi-continuous set function is upper hemi-continuous, so the Caltech note is right (if it follows the Wikipedia defintions). Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @Vasting Upvoted but I've gone through the wiki pages of "semi-continuity" and "hemi-continuity". Where do they say that an upper semi-continuous set function is upper hemi-continuous?

Answer (score 4):

A correspondence $\Gamma:X\rightrightarrows Y$ is UHC at $x\in X$ if for every open subset $O$ of $Y$ with $\Gamma(x)\subseteq O$, $\exists\;\delta>0$ such that $\Gamma(N_{\delta, X}(x))\subseteq O$.

If the correspondence is single-valued (i.e. $\Gamma(x)=\{f(x)\}$ for all $x\in X$), the definition reduces to the definition of **Continuity**:
$f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous at $x\in X$ if for every open subset $O$ of $Y$ with $f(x)\in O$, $\exists\; \delta>0$ such that $f(N_{\delta, X}(x))\subseteq O$.

So you can say something more: *every single valued correspondence is continuous (not just upper semi-continuous)*.

Comment: I think the consequence should be:
every single-valued u.h.c. correspondence is continuous.